# What is application protocol of SNS subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

SNS allows subscriber has the following type of protocols

```
HTTP/S
Lambda
SQS
Email/JSON
Application
```

not sure what does Application protocol refers to

and how can I fill in the endpoint

```
(a example is arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:5555555555:endpoint/ADM/application-name/uuid)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SNS -- the way I see it, conceptually -- is really two different products under one AWS service.

- HTTP(S), Lambda, SQS, Email, Email/JSON, and SMS (you forgot SMS)
- Mobile push notifications (that's "application" -- mobile apps)

> For the application protocol, the endpoint is the EndpointArn of a mobile app and device.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html

Unless you are sending a mobile push notification, [you don't publish to an `EndpointArn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html).  You publish to a `TopicArn`.

For everything other than mobile push (https, email, sqs, etc.), when you send a message to a topic, it goes to *all* of the subscribers to the topic.  The individual subscribers aren't individually-addressable (unless there's been a big change that I managed to miss; I welcome correction if that is the case).

With mobile push, you can send messages singly to individually-addressable endpoints (`EndpointArn`) or to all of the endpoints subscribed to a topic.